# Query that determine network provider

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am supposed to create a query that will determine the network of an 11 digit cellphone number.

- If the cellphone number starts with `0916` or `0917`, then display `Network G`.
- If it starts with `0918` or `0920`, then display `Network S`.
- If it starts with `0922` or `0923`, then display `Network A`.

But it always prints `Network G`. Please help me!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int MobNum;

    printf("Enter11 digit mobile number: ");
    scanf("%i", &MobNum);

    if (MobNum>= 9160000000 || MobNum<= 9179999999)
        printf("Network G");

    else
    if (MobNum>= 9180000000 || MobNum<= 9209999999)
        printf("Network S");

    else
    if (MobNum>= 9220000000 || MobNum<= 9239999999)
        printf("Network A");

    else
        printf("Invalid provider");

    getch();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tests are using or(`||`) instead of and(`&&`).  Think about it: All numbers tested will be greater than `9160000000` OR less than `9179999999`.

```
    if (MobNum>= 9160000000 || MobNum<= 9179999999)
    printf("Network G");
```

should be

```
    if (MobNum>= 9160000000 && MobNum<= 9179999999)
    printf("Network G");
```

and similarly, for the other `if`s

Comment: You should also add that storing 9 billion in an `int` will probably overflow. A 32 bit `int` will only go into the 2 billions.

Comment: Hmm, although the whole approach is wrong really. Phone numbers really aren't numbers so I'd be extracting the prefix as a string and then doing a table comparison.